# get invalid_grant - Malformed auth code when trying to get access token from authorization code for sign in with Google

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I'm creating a Javascript application that allows the users to sign in with Google.

When I try to sign in with Google I get redirected to my application with a querystring containing an authorization code, like this `http://localhost:3000?code=XXXXXXX`

Now I want to get the access token from this authorization code.
I'm trying this way:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let code = urlParams.get('code');

axios
      .request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        data: {
          code: decodeURIComponent(code as string),
          client_id: 'XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          client_secret: 'XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          redirect_uri: myRedirectUri,
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          scope: 'openid',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

But the response of the call is this:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Malformed auth code."
}
```

I've already read similar questions about "Malformed auth code" problem but most of them say to decode the authorization code as I'm doing.

Comment: Is this supposed to be client-side code? If so, then you are doing things fundamentally wrong to begin with there already - the `client_secret` is named like that for a reason, this value must never be exposed publicly.

Comment: @CBroe I've added the 2 lines that read "code" parameter from url. Yes it is client-side code, so yes I guess client_secret should not be exposed publicly

Comment: URLSearchParams already applies URL-decoding of the parameter values, so the additional `decodeURIComponent` is most certainly wrong. But so is using this flow on the client side to begin with - you really need to use [OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) instead here.